# Retrieve the list of dynamic properties added to class in MATLAB OOP

Tags: matlab, oop, metaclass, dynamic-properties

With MATLAB it is possible to add dynamic properties to a class instance like this:

```
% Define a class supporting for dynamic properties
classdef DynamicClass < dynamicprops
end

% Add a dynamic property named 'toto' to some instance
c = DynamicClass();
c.addprop('toto');
```

Anyhow I did not find a way to later obtain the list of dynamic properties through reflection, indeed:

```
m = metaclass(c);
```

returns an empty list for properties:

```
PropertyList: [0x1 meta.property]
```

Even listing properties in `dynamicprops` superclass returns an empty list:

```
m.SuperClassList(1).PropertyList ==> 0x1 property array
```

Is there a way to obtain *(through reflection)* the list of dynamic properties added to a class ?

NB: Some workaround would be to maintain manual list `newprop(end+1) = c.addprop(...)` but it's not very practical to pass to another base class (where til now I was working with reflection to obtain information about properties in the child class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic properties are **not** properties of the class, they're properties only of the object - note that if `DynamicClass` inherits from `dynamicprops`, then different objects of class `DynamicClass` can have a different set of properties:

```
>> a = DynamicClass;
>> b = DynamicClass;
>> a.addprop('hello');
>> a
a = 
  DynamicClass with properties:

    hello: []
>> b
b = 
  DynamicClass with no properties.
```

For this reason, you're not going to be able to get any information about them via reflection, which is by definition getting information about the class.

You've given a solution (use `properties` to retrieve a list the names of all properties of the object, dynamic or not, then use `findprop` to get the property itself, and then get information about the property).

This is likely to work OK in most cases, but note that `properties` only returns a list of the properties that are both `Hidden = false` and `GetAccess = public` (and that's true even if you call `properties` inside a method of the object). By default, properties added via `addprop` meet both of those criteria, but it's possible to change their attributes after adding them, and they won't show up with your solution. The same goes if you call `fieldnames` on the object.

Another thing that might work for you would be to use `isprop` to directly check whether the object has a property of interest. This works even if the property is `Hidden`, or `GetAccess = private`. Usefully, `isprop` works on arrays of objects, so you can create an array of objects of class `DynamicClass`, then apply `isprop` to get an array of logicals.

But the only way I know of reliably getting everything (private or not, hidden or not, and whether you know the names of the properties beforehand or not) is to just dump the object into a struct temporarily, then get the fieldnames, as @Marek suggests.

Comment: Interesting additional notes indeed. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
cs = struct(c)
```

if it's only for listing and accessing the names of the properties, this should be sufficient

```
fieldnames( cs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to retrieve meta information even for dynamic properties. I'm using `properties` to obtain the list of properties *(this includes dynamic ones)* and `findprop` to retrieve information through reflection in base class:

```
function [] = baseClassRoutine(obj)

    propNames = properties(obj);
    propCount = length(propNames);

    for idx = 1:propCount,

        propName = propNames{ki};
        propMeta = obj.findprop(propName);

        ... So now can inspect meta about all properties (including dynamic ones) ...

    end

end
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. One other comes to mind:  Rather than using the built-in dynamicprops, you could override subsref and subsasgn to mimic dynamic properties.